# JPA native query to return the entity with fields from multiple tables

Tags: java, jpa

I have a query in JPA NativeSql, where I do "unions" of tables and joins. I made an entity with all the query fields which are from multiple tables. So I can not do  "@Column" "@ table" as usual with JPA.

How could I set the given values ​​of the query to my entity?

Answer (score 10):

You can map the columns returned by your native SQL query to your entity by using [`@SqlResultSetMapping`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html).

[Example](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/SqlResultSetMapping):

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT o.id AS order_id, " +
        "o.quantity AS order_quantity, " +
        "o.item AS order_item, " +
        "i.name AS item_name, " +
    "FROM Order o, Item i " +
    "WHERE (order_quantity > 25) AND (order_item = i.id)",
    "OrderResults");

@SqlResultSetMapping(name="OrderResults", 
    entities={ 
        @EntityResult(entityClass=com.acme.Order.class, fields={
            @FieldResult(name="id", column="order_id"),
            @FieldResult(name="quantity", column="order_quantity"), 
            @FieldResult(name="item", column="order_item")
        })
    },
    columns={
        @ColumnResult(name="item_name")}
)
```

More examples can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-query-native).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overloaded [EntityManager#createNativeQuery(sql,resultClass)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) method for this.

Answer (score 2):

Why not put the NATIVE SQL into a view?  Then just create an entity mapped to the view like any normal entity would be mapped to table.  The only difference being you cannot insert, update or delete entities based off of the view.

Comment: It's what tou trying to do, the entity, you have an example of it?

Comment: Make the view in the database

Comment: I did  an entity with annotation "@ entity" and  the variables related to the query. So I did, "Query query = manager.createNativeQuery (sql.toString (), Cep.class);". Now the missing part of setting pair aminha entity values ​​return. I wish it were like this: "List results = <Cep> query.getResultList ();"

Answer (score 0):

IMHO using DAOs with JPA isn't a good idea. But have a look at the [Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html). You can construct such queries like the one you described with the [CriteriaBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html).

Comment: Whoops...didn't read that. Do you use EclipseLink? EclipseLink knows Unions.

Answer (score 0):

`JPA` native `SQL` is same as generic `SQL`. You can do `union` operation same as `SQL` query do. But, if you want to do it with `JPQL`, than you need to use `EclipseLink`, becasue  `JPQL` of `JPA` does not support of Union operation.

Comment: Exactly, not support, so use native query, the problem lies in the return of the query, how can I to set for my entity, since the fields are from several tables at once?