# JPA - One to Many Mapping using Native Query

Tags: java, jpa

I've a SQL Query which returns one to many mapping data, for example I've JOB table along with multiple one to one dependent tables and a Warning Table with one-many mapping. 
JOB 1 can have n number of warnings to it.

Right now we are handling it from Java logic but Is it possible to achieve it using JPA Native Query?

I see the same scenario's mentioned before [How to map native sql results to oneToMany field with SqlResultSetMapping in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397019/how-to-map-native-sql-results-to-onetomany-field-with-sqlresultsetmapping-in-jpa)
This is the exact thing I'm looking for ? Will the Entity take care when used with native Query?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.

Comment: @DimaSan I'm just trying to validate the approach that I'm taking is valid else there is an another way in JPA to do it. An Example would also help because I could not find one.

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/5000__JPA_Query_Native_Query_Result_Class.htm and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092763/jpa-native-query-to-return-the-entity-with-fields-from-multiple-tables

Comment: @DimaSan This is the exact requirement I've http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397019/how-to-map-native-sql-results-to-onetomany-field-with-sqlresultsetmapping-in-jpa

Comment: Still not sure what's expected here. You have one class, but you want to load all the OneToMany joined entities? You can just use `EntityManager.find` if you're looking by id, and if you're not searching by id, simply fetch all the fields from the main entity's table. The collections that hold the child-entities will be lazily loaded in that case, even if they're marked as eager, because the fetching query is native.